# Php and ajax compare issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm ajaxing over to this php file.

```
$a = 'old';
$b = 'new';
if ($_POST['info-type'] == $a || $b)
{
    $info = $_POST['info-type'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tld` WHERE type = '".$var."'";
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tld` ";


$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<div>'.$row['something'].'</div>';
}
```

The data posted is either `'all'` `'new'` or `'old'`.

If I send the data as either `new` or `old`, the script works and outputs as expected.
If the posted data is neither new or old but all instead, it fails and don't show any errors or respond anything back (I've monitored via dev tools as well).

So, I tried this:

```
if ($_POST['info-type'] == $a || $b)
{
    $info = $_POST['info-type'];
    $var = "SELECT * FROM `tld` WHERE type = '".$var."'";
} elseif ($_POST['info-type'] == 'all')
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tld` ";
}
```

But the script still fails. If i fully remove the `IF` statements and use the query without the `WHERE` clause like it is after the elseif, it works?

Comment: Answers are flooding (in 2 seconds i see 3 answer)!

Comment: How can this work? You are overwriting your `$query` variable so the `POST` variables are never used.

Comment: @jeroen +1 For pointing out The SQL Injection bug.

Comment: @AsheshKumar Scratch that, a white-list effectively avoids sql injection and that query is never used...

Comment: Will wrapping the variable in htmlspecialchars() be enough to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: @AshleyBrown No, normally (without the whitelist...) you would need `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or a prepared statement.

Comment: @jeroen If i were to use jh314's answer would wrapping 
`$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['info-type']);`
Be enough to cover sql injections?
At least for that query

Comment: @AshleyBrown Yes, although I personally would always use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare `$_POST['info-type']` with both `$a` and `$b`:

```
if ($_POST['info-type'] == $a || $_POST['info-type'] == $b)
```

---

The problem with what you have is that `$_POST['info-type'] == $a || $b` sees if `$_POST['info-type'] == $a` is true OR if `$b` is true.

Since `$b` is true (it is non-empty string), the `if` condition will always be true.

---

If `$_POST['info-type']` can only be `all` `new` or `old`, then the following will be more elegant:

```
if ($_POST['info-type'] == 'all')
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tld` ";
}
else // info type will be old or new
{
    $info = $_POST['info-type'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tld` WHERE type = '".$info."'";
}
```

Comment: $_POST['info-type'] == $a xor $b is there any problem with that also?

Comment: But why do people say there is a problem with `xor` when it works?
docs say
Xor TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE, but not both.

Since it can either only be one of them as you say, in which it can only be one, surely, the people are wrong?

Comment: @AshleyBrown The problem is that `xor` returns a boolean value and not a string, so comparing it to your POST value (if you use parenthesis...) does not make a lot of sense (`xor`-ing two different strings will always return `false` by the way). Also, take a look at the operator precedence of php, you will be xor-ing `$_POST['info-type'] == $a` with `$b` which also does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is very odd:

```
if ($_POST['info-type'] == $a || $b) {
```

You probably intended:

```
if ($_POST['info-type'] === $a || $_POST['info-type'] === $b) {
```

Also, in this case `===` is good since the type of both variables is `string`.

`$_POST['info-type'] == $a || $b` will always be true if `$b` is *truethy* (which it is).

Comment: $_POST['info-type'] == $a xor $b is there any problem with that also?

Comment: Yes, that also doesn't work. An alternative that does work is: `in_array($_POST['info-type'], array($a, $b))`

Comment: But I just tried it and it seems to work when I post all. Why does this work then?

Comment: It shouldn't work. Are you sure you're testing this correctly?

Comment: Stack overflow should REALLY allow more than one answer to be accepted.

Comment: yes, i just literally just replaced `$a || $b`   `$a xor $b` and it works